# Session being destroyed after redirect laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I'm working on a log-in form, Everything is working fine until i use `return redirect()->home();`. If i use `return view('/');` everything works fine and the sessions will persist.

Login method:`public function store(Request $request){

```
    $email = $request->email;
    $password = $request->password;

    if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])){
    return redirect()->home();

    }else{  
        return back();
     }
 }

Route: Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {


   Route::get('/', 'ContactController@index')->name('home');
})
```

what i gathered is that the problem is the **redirect function** i searched the whole internet for a fix but i could't find any help for laravel 5.4 .

Comment: I think problem lies in middleware... Maybe your session is not creating properly and its getting destroyed when you move to hom epage

Comment: I tried with middleware and without middleware the end result stays the same. I just find it bizarre that when i use "return view" it works fine but when i use "return redirect session gets destroyed.